# Iterating over a map of ints and objects

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator

I have a class called SAR that contains a map with int key values and object data values of my SARdataPoint type.  The SARdataPoint type has a function int getDate() which I would like to call for each object contained in the map.  I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how to accomplish this.  I think I'm close.

```
class SAR
{
public:
    // other attributes removed for compactness
    std::map<int, SARdataPoint> data;
}; // end of class SAR

void SAR::printSAR()
{
    for(auto iter = this->data.cbegin(); iter != this->data.cend(); ++iter)
    {
        std::cout << iter->getDate() << '\n'; //incorrect but close?
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how to implement this?

Comment: Next time please include the exact error message you get.

Comment: Without the error message and a minimal example to try to compile it myself, the only thing I can see is that you try to access the getDate member of a dereferenced `iter`. But `iter` dereferences into key-value pair. I.e. you would have to do `(*iter).second.getDate()` (first instead of second would be the int key). Does that help?

Comment: I'll be sure to include error messages next time, as well as compilable code.  Thanks.

Comment: Also, thanks for leading me to learn the meaning (*iter).whatever and iter->whatever

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an std::map, which is a collection of std::pairs. Each std::pair has a key (pair::first) and a value (pair::second). I believe your iteration loop is correct. But to call ::getDate() on an std::pair is wrong. What you need to do is the following:

```
std::cout << iter->second.getDate() << std::endl;
```

Another option to iterate through the entire map would be to use a range-based `for`

```
for(auto const& d : data) {
    std::cout << d.second.getDate() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I get this error using iter->second.getDate()...looking into it.

SAR.cc:102:39: error: passing ‘const SARdataPoint’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘int SARdataPoint::getDate()’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

Comment: @user3689202 that's a different issue, regarding const-correctness.  Post a new question if you can't figure it out.